# Is there any way to rollback the action of batch class once it is processed?

Tags: apex, batch

How to perform rollback action in Salesforce, once a batch class is processed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It cannot be done.**

A rollback is specific to a single transaction. A batch spreads a logical operation across several transactions. They are mutually exclusive. Consider, for example, that the most pertinent piece of documentation relating to the rollback functionality is titled **[Transaction Control](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_transaction_control.htm)**

> ## [Transaction Control](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_transaction_control.htm)
>
> All requests are delimited by the trigger, class method, Web Service, Visualforce page or anonymous block that executes the Apex code. If the entire request completes successfully, all changes are committed to the database. For example, suppose a Visualforce page called an Apex controller, which in turn called an additional Apex class. Only when all the Apex code has finished running and the Visualforce page has finished running, are the changes committed to the database. If the request does not complete successfully, all database changes are rolled back.

Another major problem with what you want to do is that even if your batch just performs a field update, that can have downstream effects. Your batch might also cause callouts, email sends, etc.